# Почему выдает AttributeError при попытке использовать removesuffix('string')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

```
STR = 'test string'
STR.removesuffix('string')
print(STR)
```

По идее сейчас в консоль должна вывестись строка 'test ', но почему-то выдает ошибку.
Вот ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removesuffix'
```

В ошибке четко сказано что нельзя использовать строку в этой функции. Но почему? В документации сказано что нужно использовать именно строку. Тогда почему выдает эту ошибку?
Я даже думал что у меня битая стандарт либа, поэтому скопировал код конкретно этой функции из интернета, но это все равно не помогло.

Comment: Судя по всему это просто магия.

Comment: Моя версия Python: 3.8.7

Answer (score 3):

Открываем офф документацию и ищем метод `str.removesuffix`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix

В описании видим: *New in version 3.9.*, что переводится: *Новое в версии 3.9.*

Comment: Я понимаю. Но тогда встает вопрос: Почему эта функция есть в 3.8.7 и почему в 3.7.3 при копировании кода этой функции, все работало?

Comment: Всё работало, потому что Вы запускали этот код с помощью Python 3.9.

Comment: К вашему сведению: У меня Windows 7. И она не поддерживает Python 3.9. Следовательно я никогда (вообще) не использовал Python 3.9

Comment: Да и в первом комментарии я ясно сказал что В 3.7.3! А не в 3.9.

Comment: Как Вы запускаете разными версиями? Что выдаёт запуск этих версий с флагом `-V`?

Comment: Я же сказал никак. Все это произошло на Windows 7. А на ней в данный момент установлен Python 3.8.7. Одна версия. А Python 3.7.3 я использовал полгода назад.

Comment: @Blit Gaming Не знаю как работало раньше но в любом случае оно не должно работать для python ниже 3.9. Ошибка в данном случае в том что оно работало хотя недолжно судя по Вашему описанию..

Comment: Я всё понимаю, но тогда почему эта функция есть в Python 3.8.7? Питон у меня официальный. Следовательно если она есть в этой версии, значит работать должна.